# Simple_form - How to add field name to error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have tweaked the bootstrap wrapper so that now I display all inline errors as a block above the simple_form field.

The form is a registration Devise form, specifically from the rails-prelaunch-signup composer app. How can I include the name of the field in the error message?

At the moment I am getting "isn't valid" or "can't be blank", however I would like something like "Email can't be blank".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the error message in the model:

```
validates :email, presence: { error_message: "Email can't be blank" }
```

Comment: This adds it manually for one field – how about automatically for all fields?

Answer (score 4):

Simpleform refers to rails localization if no error message is set in the model. So, if you want to add the attributes name to each error message, you could add something like this in your locale-file:

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      blank: "%{attribute} can't be blank"
      invalid: "%{attribute} isn't valid"
```

Where `%{attribute}` is the placeholder where the fields name will be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

To add the attribute name on every error message, you can use the `full_error` helper instead of the classic `error` helper

Directly in your form

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.input_field :username %>
  <%= f.full_error :username %>

  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

Or in your custom wrappers

```rb
# config/initializers/simple_form.rb

SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # ...

  config.wrappers :vertical_form do |b|
    # ...
    b.use :label
    b.use :input
    b.use :full_error
  end
end
```